# how to extract random soap xml payload using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, soap, plsql

I have the following SOAP XML payload:

```
    <Errors>
        <Error Code="386" NodeList="FAX=+52 808 669.6271" RecordID="ROOT" 
               ShortText="Invalidfax number" Status="Not Processed" />
        <Error Code="1000386" NodeList="Contact Title=empty" RecordID="ROOT" ShortText="Contact Title is required" 
               Status="Not Processed" />
        <Error Code="311" NodeList="Contact First Name=empty" RecordID="ROOT" ShortText="Required data missing: first name"
               Status="Not Processed" />
        <Error Code="310" NodeList="Contact Last Name=empty" RecordID="ROOT" ShortText="Required data missing: last name" 
               Status="Not Processed" />
        <Error Code="316" NodeList="Contact Phone=empty" RecordID="ROOT" ShortText="Required data missing: phone number"
               Status="Not Processed" />
    </Errors>
```

The number of error records to be received is random, from 1 to "N".

I can parse the following payload when it has just #1 error record, executing:

```
        vxmlns := 'xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"';
        vCode :=  xmltype.getClobVal(vXml.extract('//Error/@Code', vxmlns));
        vNodeList :=  xmltype.getClobVal(vXml.extract('//Error/@NodeList', vxmlns));
        vShortText :=  xmltype.getClobVal(vXml.extract('//Error/@ShortText', vxmlns));
        vStatus :=  xmltype.getClobVal(vXml.extract('//Error/@Status', vxmlns));
        vType := xmltype.getClobVal(vXml.extract('//Error/@RecordID', vxmlns));
```

How can I process this payload in order to process each error record individually ?

An desirable output could be:

```
Array[0]= "386 | FAX=+52 808 669.6271 | ROOT | Invalid fax number | Not Processed"
Array[1]= "1000386 |Contact Title=empty |ROOT| Contact Title is required |Not Processed"
.....
.....
Array[4]= "316 | Contact Phone=empty | ROOT | Required data missing: phone number | Not Processed"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [XMLTable query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5093):

```
select *
from XMLTable(
  '/Errors/Error'
  passing XMLType('<Errors>
        <Error Code="386" NodeList="FAX=+52 808 669.6271" RecordID="ROOT" 
               ShortText="Invalidfax number" Status="Not Processed" />
        <Error Code="1000386" NodeList="Contact Title=empty" RecordID="ROOT" ShortText="Contact Title is required" 
               Status="Not Processed" />
        <Error Code="311" NodeList="Contact First Name=empty" RecordID="ROOT" ShortText="Required data missing: first name"
               Status="Not Processed" />
        <Error Code="310" NodeList="Contact Last Name=empty" RecordID="ROOT" ShortText="Required data missing: last name" 
               Status="Not Processed" />
        <Error Code="316" NodeList="Contact Phone=empty" RecordID="ROOT" ShortText="Required data missing: phone number"
               Status="Not Processed" />
    </Errors>')
  columns code number path '@Code',
    nodeList varchar2(30) path '@NodeList',
    RecordID varchar2(10) path '@RecordID',
    shortText varchar2(40) path '@ShortText',
    status varchar2(20) path '@Status'
);

      CODE NODELIST                       RECORDID   SHORTTEXT                                STATUS             
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---------------------------------------- --------------------
       386 FAX=+52 808 669.6271           ROOT       Invalidfax number                        Not Processed       
   1000386 Contact Title=empty            ROOT       Contact Title is required                Not Processed       
       311 Contact First Name=empty       ROOT       Required data missing: first name        Not Processed       
       310 Contact Last Name=empty        ROOT       Required data missing: last name         Not Processed       
       316 Contact Phone=empty            ROOT       Required data missing: phone number      Not Processed
```

Change the `passing` clause to take your SOAP payload - you haven't shown where that's coming from so you'll have to adapt this yourself. And you can make the select list manipulate the generated columns into whatever format you need, instead of using `select *`.